# Tabs Vertical? (Tabbed View)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, view, tabs, alignment

I'm trying to make the tabs in **TabbedViewNavigatorApplication** and **ViewNavigator** line up **vertically** instead of the original horizontal.

To be able to manipulate the tabBar I've followed this guide: http://devgirl.org/2011/06/14/flex-4-5-mobile-development-tabs-on-top/

I've managed to, via the guide, place the tabBar at the top of the screen.
So now the last thing left to do, how do I align the tabs vertical? I wan't one tab per row, as if they were buttons lying in a VGroup.

Should I use any kind of **rotation** to turn the tabBar 90 degrees or can I **align the Tabs vertically**? Should I manipulate the "TabbedViewNavigatorSkin" or in the TabbedViewNavigatorApplication.

**How I want it to look:** (picture has been Photoshopped for show)
http://imageshack.us/a/img96/2461/1234yl.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take the TabbedViewNavigatorSkin and modify it. if you are lucky, its just a matter of providing the layout orientation from horizontal to vertical

Comment: How would I do that? There's no "Horizontal", "Vertical" or "Orientation" code in the skin. Any tips on what and where to write? :o